# got error while update table with use of update trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, database-trigger

```
SELECT @idTable = T.id          
FROM sysobjects P JOIN sysobjects T ON P.parent_obj = T.id          
WHERE P.id = @@procid   

-- Get Modified columns
SELECT 
    @modifiedColumns = ISNULL(@modifiedColumns + ', ', '') + name          
FROM 
    syscolumns t         
WHERE 
    id = @idTable  
    AND CONVERT(VARBINARY, REVERSE(COLUMNS_UPDATED())) & POWER(CONVERT(bigint, 2),  colorder - 1) > 0
```

I have written above code in an update trigger. I got below error for this when I update table data.

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint

Comment: i have table with more than 100 columns for above update.

Comment: bigint - 2^63, your magic bits - 2^100

Comment: Also VARBINARY might have length specified. Unless you are okay with VARBINARY(1).

Comment: Any other solution for this ?

Comment: What do you need this for in the end?

Comment: i want updated columns  to use in Store procedure. i will pass this columns to SP from trigger